# Stuck setting up a package as well as removing that package. Can't use apt now

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

So I have a .deb package downloaded. I installed it using `sudo apt install ...` but it didn't work correctly. I tried removing it using `sudo apt purge ...` and it said that it can't remove a few directories (\opt... and \var\opt...) so I removed them manually.

I tried installing the package again and it got stock on "Setting up..." for hours. It wouldn't let me shut down my computer (the option was greyed out) so I force shut it down.

Now I can't use apt. Whenever I do, I get `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.` but that **doesn't work**. It gets stuck on Setting up... again.

I tried this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates

sudo rm *

sudo apt-get update
```

and then `sudo apt remove` but then it gets stuck on Removing...

Whenever I try to install something else, it also tries to set up this package and gets stuck.

I don't know what to do, I just want apt/dpkg to jsut ignore this package, not try to set it up or remove it otherwise it always gets stuck and locks apt.

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48726142/16573616)

Comment: @crpb that did it, thank you!